# Is it possible to get the position of an op in QuillJS?

Tags: javascript, quill

I'm trying to implement a replacement feature that automatically replaces `[[https://some.link.url|Some text]]` with a link to `https://some.link.url` with text `Some text`. To do this, I can traverse through the array of ops from `quill.getContents()`.  I'd like to use `updateContents` to make the replacements, but to do that, I'd need to know the position of the operation containing the [[x|y]] syntax in the editor, so that in my `updateContents` call, I could `retain` that many characters before applying the `delete` and `insert`.

Any advice here?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do but calculating [op length](https://github.com/quilljs/delta/blob/master/lib/op.js#L55) is easy. You can calculate the length of previous ops while you iterate the ops until you reach the op you want to update.

You can also use the [text-change event](http://quilljs.com/docs/api/#text-change).